# Is OSBA the only way to connect Azure CosmosDB within AKS pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks

I have a Java pod application which connect to CosmosDB using the default connection string. The pod runs perfectly on my local minikube. But it has connection exception when I deploy it to my AKS.

The pod keep crashing with this MongoDB error.

> Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for server that matches...
>   Client view of cluster state is ... xxx.documents.azure.com:10255

Looks like it cannot reach the CosmosDB. At first I think it is because the default Network security rules block the outgoing port 10255. Then I add a NSG to that resource group. Add the outgoing rule on port 10255. It does not solve the problem.

Then I stumble upon this article. [CosmosDB on AKS using OSBA](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/deploy-mean-cosmosdb-osba-aks/)
Is it the only way? do I have to use OSBA to access a public CosmosDB?

Connection string copy from Azure portal

> mongodb://mycompany:some_base64_encrypted_stuff@mycompany.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb

[error log of my pod](https://gist.github.com/maxiwu/3a151580801b6b2d7877bc77c15b405f)

**UPDATE:**
turns out the spring-boot-starter 2.1.0 is using mongodb-driver 3.8.2.
the mongodb-driver appends :27017 to my connection string. I have updated it to 3.10.2. Now that the connection string is correct. My program running in Kubernetes is giving me UnknownHostException mydoc.documents.azure.com.
I am guessing there could be a problem caused by build docker image in windows and then run it on alpine.

**UPDATE:**
I think I am getting very close to the answer. The problem is from the kubernetes cluster. My cluster contains two nodes. I create another cluster with single node. Deploy my program to it and it connects to CosmosDB without error.
But I do not know how to debug kubernetes cluster.

Comment: you dont need outgoing port exposed on NSG, are you using network policies (in kubernetes, not in azure)?

Comment: oh, I need to modify kubernetes network policies? How?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using network policies, you can use the sample network policy to allow all egress traffic:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

If you are not using Network policies, connection should just work, you dont need OSBA. You can fine tune the network policy later to make it more restrictive.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

ps. if you are using istio with certain settings your outbound requests will be also blocker, you'd need to account for that as well

Comment: I am not using any network policy. Also not using istio. I could figure out why my pod cannot reach CosmosDB. I will try to add the egress policy which you provide.

Comment: After adding the policy. My pod gives me Unknown Host exception. mydb.documents.azure.com. Do I need to setup DNS in AKS?

Comment: no, it should be working by default, how did you create aks? are all the pods in kube-system running?

Comment: I have the default namespace and a completely clean test namespace. service running on default are kubernetes, helloworld which has been running for 30d. I deployed my CosmosDB testing pod inside test namespace. I create my cluster using Azure portal.

Comment: well, that doesnt really help. anyway, if you dont really know what network policies are in kubernetes you are most likely not using them. so networking wise outbound traffic isnt being blocked, check your cosmos connection string